# Chart: move majorgrids when scrolling

Tags: c#, scroll, graph

I have a chart control with a bargraph which has to ability to zoom and scroll.
Is there a way where I can get the grid to scroll with the graph when it is scrolling. Right now when I scroll, the grid updates its values according to what is being shown. I would like the grid to not change value, but to chage position according to scroll

[image: 0 scroll]
[image: scrolled]